# ShowPopupAsync inside a contentview in .net MAUI

Tags: .net, maui, contentview

I created two pages in maui app: a **ContentView** and a **ContentPage**. Inside the ContentView component, I need to call a popup and show some contents in the page. In my current Implementation on ContentView, I declared a bindable property of type ContentPage for the reason of using the instance to call the ShowPopupAsync method.

Bindable Property in the nxi-lookup.xaml.cs

```
    public BindableProperty ParentPageProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Page),
    typeof(ContentPage),
    typeof(nxi_lookup),
    defaultValue: null,
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);
```

my contentpage xaml

```
 <custom:nxi_lookup Page="{Binding Page,Source={x:Reference Production}}" Margin="0,0,10,10" WidthValue="10"  LabelText="Lookup 1" IsRequired="True"/>
```

Actual usage for popup inside the contentview

```
     if (Page != null)
        {
            var popup = new nxi_popup();
            var content = new nxi_lookupcontent();
            popup.Content = content;
            await Page.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
        }
```

Error   XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Page", or mismatching type.

I tried changing the type of the bindable property but does not work. I expected to bind the contentpage to my property in content view.

Is there any way to properly implement popup in a contentview?

Comment: But "Production" that you reference in the binding does not have Page property probably

Answer (score 0):

The offical document said:

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable
> property identifier must match the property name specified in the
> Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

So you can change the code `public BindableProperty ParentPageProperty =` to `public BindableProperty PageProperty =`.

In addition, did you [create accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties#create-accessors) for the bindable property?

Comment: Thanks I have already created  the accessors and renamed the bindable property in a correct format but unfortunately It does not work but I was able to solve it with a different implementation. Instead Binding the instance of the ContentPage to a porperty of the ContentView, I directly called the Parent  Class inside of my content view and was able to implement popup.

Comment: Yes, the contenview.Parent will get the instance of the page. But the error message means the bindable property created wrong. Whats the `typeof(nxi_lookup)`, you can try to change it to the`typeof(ContentView)`. And l'm glad to know your problem was resolved. @MarkKenithSimbajon